# What is the Delphi equivalent for LPLONG?

Tags: delphi, dll, interop

I have to access several functions of a DLL written in c from Delphi (currently Delphi7).
I can do it without problems when the parameters are scalar 
(thanks to the examples found in this great site!), but I have been stuck for some time when in the parameters there is a pointer to an array of Longs.

This is the definition in the header file of one of the functions:

> BOOL __stdcall BdcValida (HANDLE h, LPLONG opcl);

*(opcl is an array of longs)*

And this is a portion of my Delphi code:

```
type
  TListaOpciones= array of LongInt; //I tried with static array too! 
  Popcion = ^LongInt; //tried with integer, Cardinal, word...  
var
  dllFunction: function(h:tHandle;  opciones:Popcion):boolean;stdcall;
  arrayOPciones:TListaOpciones;
  resultado:boolean;
begin
  .....
  I give values ​​to aHandle and array arrayOPciones
  .....
  resultado:=dllFunction(aHandle, @arrayopciones[0]);
end;
```

The error message when executing it is:

> "Project xxx raised too many consecutive exceptions: access violation
>   at 0x000 .."

What is the equivalent in Delhpi for LPLONG?  Or am I calling the function in an incorrect way?
Thank you!

Comment: I must admit that I find the function call confusing, in that if opcl really is a pointer to an array, and not, say, a single variable, I don't see how the DLL knows how big that array is - that is to say there is no parameter telling it unless it is stored in whatever h is pointing to.

Comment: The DLL knows the size of the array, it varies depending on the context and we know it through functions of the dll that inform it.

Comment: You are saying there is a different function to set the array length for the DLL. Are you sure that you are setting it correctly? Maybe you are passing a value that is too high (probably by one).

Comment: Relevant bits of the code are missing to understand who and where the memory is allocated and freed and how the size of the array is passed.

Answer (score 3):

`LONG` maps to `Longint`, and `LPLONG` maps to `^Longint`. So, you have translated that type correctly.

You have translated `BOOL` incorrectly though. It should be `BOOL` or `LongBool` in Delphi. You can use either, the former is an alias for the latter.

Your error lies in code or detail we can't see. Perhaps you didn't allocate an array. Perhaps the array is incorrectly sized. Perhaps the handle is not valid. Perhaps earlier calls to the DLL failed to check for errors.

Comment: Thanks David, I've tried static and dynamic arrays, correctly allocated. The Handle is valid (it works in other functions of the dll).
I think earlier calls to the DLL are not the problem (if I call another function instead it does not give an error)
I will correct the BOOL and try

Comment: Changing the `BOOL` won't make a difference. Wherever your problem is, it's not in the code presented.